# Convert hexadecimal field into daily availability (in general and in T-SQL)

Tags: sql, hex

I recently started trying to get some data out of an old database that I'm not super familiar with.  One of the things that it has is a daily availability column, that supposedly represents when a resource is available in a day.  Unfortunately that field is a hexadecimal field like this one:

```
0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF3F0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I believe this represents 6:00 AM - 4:30 PM, I'm not exactly sure how, this isn't my strong suit.  It appears that every 15 characters represents an hour, the only confusing part is the 3F for the end of 4:30.

So the question is how do I manipulate/parse this in SQL to get the start and end values out once I figure out how the data is formatted?

Here's a bit more sample data:

```
0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000E0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0700000000000000
```

This one represents 4:29 PM - 10:59 PM

```
0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000C0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0F00000000000000
```

This one 4:30 PM - 11:00 PM

```
0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000C0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000000000000000000000000000
```

This one represents 4:30 PM - 10:00 PM

Comment: Added some more sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your math breaks down like this:

1. 3600 seconds in an hour
2. 15 characters representing an hour
3. 3600/15 = 240 seconds for each character
4. Hex F = 16.  240/16 = 15 seconds for each number.

Turns out, it takes 2 digits at a time, thats why you see a 0C and an F0.

This needs more polish, but its all the time I have.

```
declare @binaryS binary(180)
set @binaryS = 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000E0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0700000000000000
declare @s varchar(max)
set @s = Convert(varchar(max), @binaryS, 2)
declare @seconds int
set @seconds = 0
declare @i int
set @i = 1
declare @t datetime
set @t = Convert(datetime, '01/01/2014', 101)
WHILE (@i <= 360)
BEGIN
    declare @segment varchar(max)
    set @segment = substring(@s, @i, 2)
    --print '0x' + @segment
    set @seconds = (convert(int, convert(varbinary, '0x' + @segment, 1))) * 15
    set @t = DATEADD(ss,480,@t)
    --print @seconds
    if(@seconds > 0)
      print @t
    set @i = @i + 2
END
```

Quick explaination.  `@binaryS` is your db value.  Its converted to a string, then parsed 2 digits at a time.  For each iteration of the loop, 480 seconds (FF) is added to the date.  When the @seconds is not zero, it prints out the time.  So the result is every 4 minutes that is enabled.  You'd need to capture the first and last one of these for your start and end times.  The above works in an SSMS query window, but SQLFiddle cant handle it.

Comment: Makes sense, the beginning/end of an available section confuses me though.  Like for 4:30-11 it starts with C0 and ends with 0F, shouldn't those characters be flipped?

Comment: @SamC, is the field in the database a varchar(max) or a varbinary?

Comment: @SammC, That should give you a good start.  Let me know if you have questions.